# How can I fetch all the users who is liking the Community when using acts_as_votable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have **'like'** action in **communities_controller.rb**
What if I want to fetch all the users who is liking the community currently, how can I write in controller?
I'm using the gem called **acts_as_votable**

It should be something like this?

> @community = Community.find(params[:id])
>   @users = User.likes @community

**communities_controller.rb**

```
def like
    if current_user.voted_up_on? @community
        current_user.dislikes @community
        flash[:notice] = "Deleted from favorite"
    else
        current_user.likes @community
        flash[:notice] = "Added to favorite"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @community }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all users that like a community you can write

```
@community.likes
```

Look at the [acts_as_votable Documentation](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) to understand all other operations you do.

Comment: Thanks but this returns error. It seems not fetching users.. **@community.likes.order("last_signed_in_at DESC").limit(3).each do |user|**